# Location of S3 data for Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have created an Amazon S3 bucket and uploaded a flat file (the famous [Iris flower data set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) data as csv).

I would now like to create an Iris dataset flat table in Amazon Athena and query it. I just cannot find the 'Location of Input Data Set'.

How do I determine the location of my flat Iris file in the S3 bucket? Is there possibly a tutorial for the above situation (google did not help much yet)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [Amazon Athena `CREATE TABLE` documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ddl/create-table.html), the syntax to create a table is:

```
CREATE [EXTERNAL] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS]
 [db_name.]table_name [(col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment] [, ...] )]
 [COMMENT table_comment]
 [PARTITIONED BY (col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)]
 [ROW FORMAT row_format]
 [STORED AS file_format] [WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (...)] ]
 [LOCATION 's3_loc']
 [TBLPROPERTIES ( ['has_encrypted_data'='true | false',] ['classification'='aws_glue_classification',] property_name=property_value [, ...] ) ]
```

The `s3_loc` is:

> Specifies the location of the underlying data in Amazon S3 from which the table is created, for example, `s3://mystorage/`. For more information about considerations such as data format and permissions, see Create Tables From Underlying Data in Amazon S3.
>
> Use a trailing slash for your folder or bucket. Do not use file names or glob characters.
>
> Use: `s3://mybucket/myfolder/`
>
> Don't use: `s3://path_to_bucket s3://path_to_bucket/* s3://path_to-bucket/mydatafile.dat`

Therefore, if you have stored your flat file in a bucket called `my-bucket` within a directory called `iris`, you would use:

```
LOCATION s3://my-bucket/iris/
```

Note that you point to the directory, not the file. This is because many data sets are stored as multiple files (and even multiple sub-directories).

Comment: Is setting the LOCATION to a file supported? Example: LOCATION s3://my-bucket/iris/myfile.csv.gz

Comment: @CaptainCaveman No, the documentation says "Do not use file names". You must specify a directory and multiple files might be created.

Answer (score 1):

If you have AWS CLI installed, then you can use it to find the file:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket_name --recursive | grep iris_csv_file
```

Comment: Will check soon. Thanks.