# Amazon Athena set location to single csv file

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I would like to set the location value in my Athena SQL create table statement to a single CSV file as I do not want to query every file in the path. I can set and successfully query an s3 directory (object) path and all files in that path, but not a single file. *Is setting a single file as the location supported?*

Successfully queries CSV files in path:

```
LOCATION 's3://my_bucket/path/'
```

Returns zero results:

```
LOCATION 's3://my_bucket/path/filename.csv.gz'
```

Create table statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default`.`my_db` (
    `name` string,
    `occupation` string,    
    )
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    'field.delim' = ','
   ) LOCATION 's3://bucket-name/path/filename.csv.gz'
   TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

I have [read this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497898/reading-a-single-csv-file-from-s3-bucket-using-amazon-athena-and-querying-it) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017061/location-of-s3-data-for-amazon-athena), but it doesn't seem to address the same issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to query a single file with Athena? How big is this thing?

Comment: Can you try it by ending with / after gz in the location? LOCATION 's3://bucket-name/path/filename.csv.gz/'

Comment: @bzu I want to query files as they are delivered to the bucket. I have a Lambda with an s3 trigger.

Comment: @RahulDiggi I have tried adding the trailing /, and unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: You could copy it to a temporary prefix with lambda and do your query from there.

Comment: That is true but I'd rather not if querying the file in it's current path is an option. Thanks.

Comment: Not its not possible. You can query it with S3 select directly if you want. Depending on what you need, Athena may not be required at all.

Comment: @Marcin - Thank you. I didn't know the S3 Select feature existed. I implemented the solution below but it's good know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try adding path of that particular object in WHERE condition while querying:

```
SELECT * FROM default.my_db
WHERE "$path" = 's3://bucket-name/path/filename.csv.gz'
```

Comment: This worked! Note for others, when you set the location in your CREATE TABLE statement, you need to point to the directory path:  s3://bucket-name/path/ and then define the specific file in the WHERE clause. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to work. Can someone point me to the official documentation of $path?

Comment: As per this question, it was not possible before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795031/query-by-path-field